# In Revolutionary Girl Utena, what's the power to revolutionize the world?

Tags: revolutionary-girl-utena

I made [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28849/spoiler-whats-the-actual-plot-in-revolutionary-girl-utena) before but since a single answer won't suffice, I have broke it down into different post as suggested by other users. **TL;DR:** I'm tring to understand the story, **not the analogies.**

So, What is the power to bring revolution? Is it actual power (like the type you see in shounen animes) or is it just an analogy about making the world accept behaviors like homosexuality and incest (as seen in events related with Akio & Touga or Akio & Anthy)?

Answer (score 1):

## Touga's explanation in the manga

In the third volume of the manga, before their second duel together, Utena asks Touga:

> Why do you want it so much? "The power to revolutionize the world" … I've never understood it.

Touga's response to this is:

> Oh. That's easy. Tenjou, have you ever felt that you were an outsider? That this place we look down upon … It's like *another* world, far away from the *real* one? Our *true* world exists someplace *else*. We *all* want to get that world back so we can finally return to our *deepest* selves. This world we inhabit — it's like an egg … A small world encased in a *hard* shell. The chick will *die*, unborn, if it doesn't *break* through that shell … Die without ever knowing that it's a *bird*! If we don't break the *world's* shell, we'll die without beyond *born*, without knowing we can *fly*! And I *want* to fly. *That* is why I will revolutionize the world … So that I can be *myself*!

(Italics are from original text. Some of the punctuation is my own.) This implies that in the *Utena* manga, this "power to revolutionize the world" is not necessarily about physical power. Rather, it is about being able to make a proper place for oneself in the world.

## Can a similar interpretation apply to the anime?

The anime diverges from the manga somewhat in plot, but this interpretation helps clarify the anime's own discussion of the "revolution." We often are shown a sequence where the student council members say:

> If it cannot break its egg's shell, a chick will die without being born. We are the chick. The world is our egg. If we don't crack the world's shell, we will die without being born. Smash the world's shell! For the revolution of the world!

This is very similar to the second half of what Touga says in the manga. There is the same notion of self-realization and overcoming the world here. Furthermore, Mikage's response in the anime after students recount their troubles — "Your only choice is to revolutionize the world." — shares the element of "revolutionizing the world" for *personal* reasons.

When Nanami substitutes for Touga, she introduces a variant in the sequence:

> If it cannot break its egg's shell, a chick will die without being born. The chamber of freedom and the cage of freedom. Without revealing the vastness of the sky, both care for the chick. Smash the world's cage! For the revolution of the world!

The meaning of this is less immediately clear, but it does not seem inconsistent with the interpretations earlier.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the series was that every candidate had their own impression of what it meant to "revolutionize the world". When Utena finally managed to do it, I understood that she had created an alternate reality, given Anthy the opportunity to follow her there, and left Akio oblivious to its existence. This changed the world completely for all three of those parties, getting Utena out of a situation she didn't care for and offering freedom and friendship to Anthy.